# How to Stop Internet explorer shortcut keys in CDHTMLDialog Class?

Tags: mfc, dhtml, visual-c++

I am new to CDHTMLDialog in mfc.
I know how to disable Refresh keys.

Is there generic solution to disable internet shortcut keys(accelerators)?

```
  Ex: ctrl+n , ctrl+o.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override CDHtmlDialog::TranslateAccelerator

```
           if( ( GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000 ) 
            && (('N' == lpMsg->wParam)      
              || ('O' == lpMsg->wParam)     
              || ('L' == lpMsg->wParam)     
              || ('P' == lpMsg->wParam)))   
      return S_OK;
```

Answer (score 1):

Override CDHtmlDialog::TranslateAccelerator