# How to capture events fired from popup IE window

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, dhtml

I want to prevent popup IE window from IE shortcut keys.This actually I done with the help of 
newwindow2 function

```
    void CDHtmlDialogEx::OnNewWindow2(LPDISPATCH FAR* ppDisp, BOOL FAR* Cancel)
    {
     //*Cancel = FALSE;//allow
     *Cancel = TRUE;
    }
```

I want to differentiate using ppDisp to open the popup window for particular operation.

How can I do this?

**EDIT**

How to use this **ppDisp** variable?Give sample for this usage of ppDisp variable.

Regards,
Karthik

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432807/how-to-stop-internet-explorer-shortcut-keys-in-cdhtmldialog-class

Comment: ppDisp is the automate interface of the webbrowser control on the new window, that is, if you did not cancell the creation of the new window as showing here and created a new window instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ppDisp is the automate interface of the webbrowser control on the new window, that is, if you did not cancell the creation of the new window as showing here and created a new window instead.

We will not get this variable to get the document interface.